# Fast alternative to grep -f

Tags: perl, awk

file.contain.query.txt

```
ENST001

ENST002

ENST003
```

file.to.search.in.txt

```
ENST001  90

ENST002  80

ENST004  50
```

Because ENST003 has no entry in 2nd file and ENST004 has no entry in 1st file the expected output is:

```
ENST001 90

ENST002 80
```

To grep multi query in a particular file  we usually do the following:

```
grep -f file.contain.query <file.to.search.in >output.file
```

since I have like 10000 query and almost 100000 raw in file.to.search.in it takes very long time to finish (like 5 hours). Is there a fast alternative to grep -f ?

Comment: What are your needs? do wou want a file with the lines of the second filtered with the keys of the first one?

Comment: I edited the expected results

Comment: The input redirection is unnecessary.

Comment: What locale?  Try `LANG=C grep -F ...` and see if speed improves thanks to locale and (as @tripleee prudently advises) fixed string matching.

Comment: See also [my awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38386426/519360) provided to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343776/grep-f-alternative-for-huge-files).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want a pure Perl option, read your query file keys into a hash table, then check standard input against those keys:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# build hash table of keys
my $keyring;
open KEYS, "< file.contain.query.txt";
while (<KEYS>) {
    chomp $_;
    $keyring->{$_} = 1;
}
close KEYS;

# look up key from each line of standard input
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp $_;
    my ($key, $value) = split("\t", $_); # assuming search file is tab-delimited; replace delimiter as needed
    if (defined $keyring->{$key}) { print "$_\n"; }
}
```

You'd use it like so:

```
lookup.pl < file.to.search.txt
```

A hash table can take a fair amount of memory, but searches are much faster (hash table lookups are in constant time), which is handy since you have 10-fold more keys to lookup than to store.

Comment: This is Ferrari when compare with grep -f  .. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you have fixed strings, use `grep -F -f`. This is significantly faster than regex search.

Answer (score 5):

This Perl code may helps you:

```
use strict;
open my $file1, "<", "file.contain.query.txt" or die $!;
open my $file2, "<", "file.to.search.in.txt" or die $!;

my %KEYS = ();
# Hash %KEYS marks the filtered keys by "file.contain.query.txt" file

while(my $line=<$file1>) {
    chomp $line;
    $KEYS{$line} = 1;
}

while(my $line=<$file2>) {
    if( $line =~ /(\w+)\s+(\d+)/ ) {
        print "$1 $2\n" if $KEYS{$1};
    }
}

close $file1;
close $file2;
```

Comment: Your forgot to check the return value of the syscalls.

Answer (score 4):

If the files are already sorted:

```
join file1 file2
```

if not:

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using perl version 5.10 or newer, you can join the 'query' terms into a regular expression with the query terms separated by the 'pipe'. (Like:`ENST001|ENST002|ENST003`) Perl builds a 'trie' which, like a hash, does lookups in constant time. It should run as fast as the solution using a lookup hash. Just to show another way to do this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Inline::Files;

my $query = join "|", map {chomp; $_} <QUERY>;

while (<RAW>) {
    print if /^(?:$query)\s/;
}

__QUERY__
ENST001
ENST002
ENST003
__RAW__
ENST001  90
ENST002  80
ENST004  50
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql:

Importing the data into Mysql or similar will provide an immense improvement.  Will this be feasible ? You could see results in a few seconds.

```
mysql -e 'select search.* from search join contains using (keyword)' > outfile.txt 

# but first you need to create the tables like this (only once off)

create table contains (
   keyword   varchar(255)
   , primary key (keyword)
);

create table search (
   keyword varchar(255)
   ,num bigint
   ,key (keyword)
);

# and load the data in:

load data infile 'file.contain.query.txt' 
    into table contains fields terminated by "add column separator here";
load data infile 'file.to.search.in.txt' 
    into table search fields terminated by "add column separator here";
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but it will work with a bit of tweaking depending on your situation.  It will take very little memory unless you want it to be ram based.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warings;

system("sort file.contain.query.txt > qsorted.txt");
system("sort file.to.search.in.txt  > dsorted.txt");

open (QFILE, "<qsorted.txt") or die();
open (DFILE, "<dsorted.txt") or die();


while (my $qline = <QFILE>) {
  my ($queryid) = ($qline =~ /ENST(\d+)/); 
  while (my $dline = <DFILE>) {
    my ($dataid) = ($dline =~ /ENST(\d+)/);
    if ($dataid == $queryid)   { print $qline; }
    elsif ($dataid > $queryid) { break; } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little dated, but is tailor-made for simple UNIX utilities. Given:

- keys are fixed-length (here 7 chars)
- files are sorted (true in the example) allowing the use of fast merge sort

Then:

```
$ sort -m file.contain.query.txt file.to.search.in.txt | tac | uniq -d -w7

ENST002  80

ENST001  90
```

Variants:

To strip the number printed after the key, remove tac command:

```
$ sort -m file.contain.query.txt file.to.search.in.txt | uniq -d -w7
```

To keep sorted order, add an extra tac command at the end:

```
$ sort -m file.contain.query.txt file.to.search.in.txt | tac | uniq -d -w7 | tac
```