# How to filter out data from big file on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, shell

I've two files, `urls.log`(1Gb) and `ids.txt`(20M), the first file `urls.log` look like this:

```
/product/80x80/436284940/
/product/100x100/1051907917/Pavillon-2.jpg
/product/140x140/988563549/LITTLE-ROSE-Mikrofasermischung-Maxi-Slips-uni-5er-Pack.jpg
/product/100x100/504170379/Dunlop-SP-Sport-Maxx-215-40R17-87V-XL-VW1-MFS.jpg
...
```

The second file `ids.txt` look like this:

```
988563549
988563540
988563541
...
```

The result should be: (`result.txt`)

`/product/140x140/988563549/LITTLE-ROSE-Mikrofasermischung-Maxi-Slips-uni-5er-Pack.jpg`

Because `988563549` exists in `ids.txt` so we need this record in `urls.log`, otherwise, we don't need the line, and we also don't need `/product/80x80/5252352/` because it's folder not image.

What I write in PHP is:

```
$file = '/combined/combine.url.sanitized.access_log';
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) 
    {
        $handleids = fopen('/script/ids.txt', "r");
        while (($lineIds = fgets($handleids)) !== false) 
        {
            if (strpos($line, trim($lineIds)) !== false) 
            {
                file_put_contents('result.txt', $line . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($handleids);
        file_put_contents('result.txt', '=' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

This work so slowly, I calculated the time, approximately need 60 days. So how should I improve it? It is OK to use other language to achieve that, but I'm not familiar to other language, so please tell me more detail.

Comment: `file_put_contents` will create a file pointer, write to it, and close it again for each call. Seeing as you're appending in a loop, `fopen` would be the better option. Be that as it may: PHP is not really suited to process log files of 1 Gb in size. Other languages are much better equipped for this. Go, R, Python...

Comment: *This work so slowly* this is right, if you can use os fuctions to get your result eg. sed, grep, comm or write a perl / bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a file full of patterns, and another file to search for those patterns, you can use the `-f` option of `grep` (`-F` is used as your pattern file only contains fixed strings, not regex patterns):

```
grep -Ff ids.txt urls.log
```

To ignore anything that ends in a slash, you can pipe to `grep` again, using `-v` to exclude patterns this time:

```
grep -Ff ids.txt urls.log | grep -v /$ > result.txt
```

This should be faster than your PHP script. If it is still too slow, you may want to look into using Perl (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490036/fast-alternative-to-grep-f)) or Python.

Answer (score 0):

first, u can cache the ids.txt into a set.
then, start a reactor thread to iterate urls.log each line into a queue,
and start some work threads to consume this queue, in each work thread, u use the set which made by ids.txt to filter each line in urls.log.